# Trying to have header back to normal when scrolling back up, it keeps looping the fadeOut

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to have header back to normal when scrolling back up, it keeps looping the fadeOut:

```
// Main content window    
$('.main').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        //header   
        $('header').slideUp(500).delay(800).fadeOut(400);
    } else {
        $('header').slideUp(500).fadeIn(400);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does **Nishit Maheta**'s solution work?

Answer (score 0):

use below code  . add [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) before animation start

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched
>   elements.

```
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {

 //header   
    $('header').stop().slideUp(500).delay(800).fadeOut(400);

  } else {

     $('header').stop().slideUp(500).fadeIn(400);
  }
```